How to exposure render settings to addon panel?
I want to exposure render settings, specifically, Frame Rate, Resolution X and Resolution Y to my addon panel for convenience, I tried:
layout.prop(data=bpy.context.scene,property="render.fps",text="Frame Rate")
layout.prop(data=bpy.types.RenderSettings,property="fps",text="Frame Rate")

But none of them worked, so is there a way to achieve this?

I figured it out, the data needs to be just the one higher level instead of two, then it works.
layout.prop(data=bpy.context.scene.render,property="fps",text="Frame Rate")

